# php explode microtime error: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php

I have this code which is showing this error in the logs. Any ideas why?

> PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1

```
$microtime = microtime(true);
list($time,$mili) = explode(".", $microtime);
```

EDIT:
Sorry forgot to mention that this error doesn't happen every time, I just noticed it in the logs. Maybe it only happens when there are no milliseconds

Example output of microtime: 1418114280.8363

Comment: @MarkBaker not when `true` has been supplied as parameter... It should be a float, unless OP is still working with PHP 4.x

Comment: Are you on a linux machine? As stated on the doc, microtime is not working on every platform. Did you see the output of microtime?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://3v4l.org/PYkhS

Comment: Have you tried to use `var_dump($microtime)` to see what it contains?

Answer (score 0):

A bit too long for a comment, but (as an alternative) try using

```
$microtime = microtime(true);
$time = floor($microtime);
$mili = fmod($microtime, 1);
```

and see what result this gives

Answer (score 0):

It works fine check it

```
echo $microtime = microtime(true);
print_r(explode(".", $microtime));
list($time,$mili) = explode(".", $microtime);
print_r($time);
echo '---';
print_r($mili);
```